# Divergent outcome from the IVF and PVF compilers

Tags: fortran, procedure

I encounter a problem when I try to compile a source code with the following module: the Intel Visual Fortran compiler would show a runtime error saying that

> error#8169: The specified interface is not declared. [FUNCTION_TEMPLATE] at line 15

while the Portland Visual Fortran compiler could run it without issuing any warning. What is wrong?

```
01  MODULE toolbox
02      IMPLICIT NONE                         
03      ABSTRACT INTERFACE                         
04          FUNCTION function_template(x) RESULT(y)   
05          IMPLICIT NONE
06          REAL, DIMENSION(:) :: x    
07          REAL, DIMENSION(SIZE(x)) :: y          
08          END FUNCTION function_template  
09          
10          FUNCTION penalty_template(x,fvec_p,proc_p) RESULT(y)                  
11          IMPLICIT NONE                                         
12          REAL, DIMENSION(:) :: x               
13          REAL, DIMENSION(:), POINTER :: fvec_p   
14          REAL :: y           
15          PROCEDURE(function_template), POINTER :: proc_p       
16          END FUNCTION penalty_template                           
17      END INTERFACE   
18  CONTAINS  
19      ...
20  END MODULE toolbox
```

Comment: Thanks. It works after adding IMPORT between line 10 and 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Fortran 2003 interface bodies do not, by default, inherit entities defined in their host scope.  Therefore, while the name `function_template` is defined in the host (through the first interface body), it is not defined in the second interface body.

You can import declarations from the host using an IMPORT statement.  An IMPORT statement before the IMPLICIT NONE directs that all entities from the host scope are inherited by the interface body.  You can restrict what is imported by listing the relevant identifiers after the import keyword which, from a style and code documentation point of view, I think is a good idea.

The Portland compiler is in error if it does not diagnose this.

(In Fortran 2008 interface bodies for separate module procedures do inherit from their host, but that is not applicable here.)